# Execute command like Start>Run in C#

Tags: c#, .net, pinvoke

I want to create a command executor like `Start > Run`. The application has a `TextBox` and when a user enters a command eg : `notepad "C:\test.txt"` it should open notepad with this file or `%PROGRAMFILES%` it should open 'Programs Files' directory.

For `%PROGRAMFILES%` and other Windows variables I can use `Environment.ExpandEnvironmentVariable` and get their path and pass to `Process.Start`

and for notepad, I can split the with space and first part goes in `FileName` and rest of string goes in `Arguments` of `ProcessStartInfo`.

But what I want to know is, how does Start > Run work ? is there something like I can execute the whole command without splitting command-line or expanding the variables ? Maybe with pinvoke ?

Comment: Perhaps you can just use the `start` command-line command?

Comment: Here you can find some details where run dialog searches - http://superuser.com/questions/87372/how-does-the-windows-run-dialog-locate-executables

Answer (score 1):

To the very best of my knowledge, the run dialog is implemented with a call to `ShellExecuteEx`. You can achieve the same with `Process.Start` and `UseShellExecute`. You do need to expand the environment variables, and split the command into filename and arguments. You already describe how to do that in your question, and, again to the best of my knowledge, there is no programmatic interface to the functionality of the Run dialog.

However, what you can do programmatically is show the Run dialog. Create an instance of the [`Shell`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb774094.aspx) object requesting the [`IShellDispatch`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg537707.aspx) interface, and then call the [`FileRun`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/gg537715.aspx) method.